# Endomorphism existence condition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I understand that an endomorphism of a vector space is a linear map $f: V \to V$.

An exercise asks me if an endomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb R^3$ exists so that $$f(1; 0; 0) = (2; 0; 1)\;\;and\;\;\;f(-1; 0; 0) = (2; 1;1)$$

Does it exist? If yes, could you provide me an example?

Comment: Maybe you did a mistake; how could $f(1,0,0)$ has different images?

Comment: I fixed it, it was a typo

Comment: But an endomorphism is particular type of function: so every point cannot has different images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Such an endomorphism cannot exist. Linear maps must take $0$ to $0$ and are of course linear. In your case you would have
$$
f(0;0;0) = f(1-1;0;0) \\= f(1;0;0) - f(1;0;0)\\ = f(1;0;0) + f(-1;0;0) \\= (2;0;1) + (2;1;1)\\ = (4;1;2) \neq (0;0;0)
$$
You could also observe that you should have $f(-1;0;0) = -f(1;0;0)$ by linearity. This is not the case with your given conditions.

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Changed it into a proper answer as you corrected the typo.

Comment: So such an endomorphism cannot exist because it is not a linear map in the first place?   ($f(−1;0;0)\;!=\;−f(1;0;0)$)

Comment: Yup. That is correct.